# iOS: How to Create and Maintain an Attribute that Affects Several Different Classes?

Tags: ios, attributes

My app is constructed with several UIViewControllers based on a UINavigationController. There are some attributes that become relevant in several different classes; for example the device (iPhone/iPad) or the device selected language (english/french/Chinese/etc...).

I assume this should be quite trivial, but I actually don't know how to do this (or how this feature is called in XCode): How can I create an attribute that will serve all classes?

Should it be located in the AppDelegate file or someplace else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), so you could share data among your UIViewControllers. Here's a nice tutorial:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/